# How do I get the full path of everywhere a JSON field occurs using FasterXML?

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

Given a JSON field name such as "my_field" and a FasterXML JSON ObjectNode, how can I walk through the JSON and get the fully qualified path of everywhere that "my_field" occurs in the JSON?

```
"top_field": {
        "mid_field": [
            {
                "my_field": true,
            },
            {
                "my_field": true,
            }
        ],
        "another_mid_field": [
            {
                "my_field": false
            }
        ]
    }
```

I would want to have the following results:

```
 top_field.mid_field[0].my_field
 top_field.mid_field[1].my_field
 top_field.another_mid_field.my_field
```

Is there a part of the FasterXML library that exposes this information without having to parse all the values of the JSON? I was previously using recursion to do so, starting from the root top_field and walking down, passing each object down as I went but that is prone to stack overflows on large JSON objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This main:

```
package jsonpath;

import java.util.List;

import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Option;
import static com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.*;

public class GetPaths {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String json = "{\"top_field\": { \"mid_field\": [ { \"my_field\": true, }, { \"my_field\": true, } ], \"another_mid_field\": [ { \"my_field\": false } ] }}";

        Configuration conf = Configuration.builder().options(Option.AS_PATH_LIST).build();
        List<String> pathList = using(conf).parse(json).read("$..my_field");
        for(String path : pathList) {
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Will output exactly

```
$['top_field']['mid_field'][0]['my_field']
$['top_field']['mid_field'][1]['my_field']
$['top_field']['another_mid_field'][0]['my_field']
```

If you do some simple string replace on that one I think it´s a nice and easy solution. I`m not sure if you can get anything similar with plain Jackson/FasterXML. JsonPath uses Jackson under the hood.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! We do use JsonPath but unfortunately are still on 0.9 where I am so cannot use this...

Comment: I guess this line "List<String> pathList = using(conf).parse(json).read("$..my_field");" should be "List<String> pathList = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(json).read("$..my_field");"

Comment: If you don`t import statically, yes.

Comment: @Homyk, what if I want to have all "my_field" under all "mid_field"? I tried "$..mid_field.myfield" but jsonpath turn that to "$..['mid_field']['my_field']" and without "." between it cannot be find.